# How To Get Item From DynamoDB Based On Multiple (one primary) Attributes Lambda/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My table structure in DynamoDB looks like the following:

uuid (Primary Key)  | ip | userAgent

From within a NodeJS function inside of lambda, I would like to get the uuid of an item whose ip and useragent match the information I provide.

`Scan` becomes less and less efficient and more expensive over time as millions of items are added to the table every week.

Here is the code I am using to try and accomplish this:

```
function tieDown(sIP, uA){
 const userQuery = {
       Key : {
         "ip" : "192.168.0.1",
         "userAgent" : "sample"
       },
       TableName: "mytable"
      };
  return ddb.get(userQuery, function(err, data){
   if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  }).promise();
}
```

When this code executes, the following error is thrown `ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`.

So I guess my questions are:

- Is it even possible to get one specific item based on non-primary attributes
- Are there any issues with the code sample I provided that could lead to this error being thrown? (I'm using `DocumentClient` so no need to explicitly declare strings, numbers etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a single item using the `get` operation without specifying the partition key, and sort key if you have one. Scans should be avoided in most cases. What you probably need is a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) that allows you to `query` by `ip` and `userAgent`. Keep in mind that the records on a GSI are not guaranteed unique, so you may get more than one result.

Comment: Was trying to avoid essentially creating a secondary table but it's that's the only solution then I guess you're correct!

Comment: Keep in mind that you can limit the projection onto the GSI to just the keys, which should be all you need for your case. At least with a GSI the data is managed for you automatically, as opposed to duplicating that data yourself. But don't be afraid of data duplication in a NoSQL world. It's the norm, which is a big change for SQL.

Comment: Something I am still getting used to :)